# Difference between curve and a function of two variables.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, soft-question, definition

Please help as I could not find out what I am missing. I can understand to an extent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve what it means to be a curve. But I cannot find what I loose if I try to define curve as function of two variable. For simplicity consider a curve in X-Y plane in such case can't we think of curve as a function of two variable?

Comment: Would you consider $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ to be a "curve", or $xy - 1 = 0$ for that matter.

Comment: A curve can be written as a set of coordinates $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. That set of coordinates will describe the curve. Notice how each coordinate is determined by a single parameter, $t$. For a surface in 3-d, you need two parameters. I.e, each point will have to be written as $(x(t,s),y(t,s),z(t,s))$. Let me know if this makes sense and if there is anything more you'd like me to explain.

Comment: @dxiv It appears to be equation rather than a function.

Comment: What a mesh.. I got confused with the most simple LOL.

Comment: @Creator You wrote `consider a curve in X-Y plane` so I thought you meant an [implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) defined by some equation $\,f(x,y)=0\,$, otherwise it's even less clear what the question meant to ask.

Comment: @divx Yes, This is the worst position,I think I had in the last so many years. Really, got confused with very simple. All my wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll end up with a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ if you try to define a curve $z = f(x,y)$ since $(x,y)\to f(x,y)$

Take the parabola as in the article for example

We have no problem looking at $y = x^2$ in $\mathbb R^2$, but in $\mathbb R^3$, the equation is independent of $z$, so $z$ takes on all values, which extends the parabola indefinitely in both $z$ directions.

Making the parabola just a curve and not a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ requires parameterized equations like

$x(t)=t$

$y(t)=t^2$

$z(t)=0$